# google.visialization classes not recognized when trying to create new DataTable for Google Charts in Angular

Tags: angular, charts, angular7, google-visualization

I installed the following library in my Angular 7 project.

> $ npm install angular-google-charts

I could use the wrapper properly, but at some point I noticed a few bugs and wanted to create new listeners for my chart. So I decided to go back to the basics and use the Google Chart library without the angular wrapper.

I have the google.visualization directory in node_modules, installed with the angular wrapper.
And the following line doesn't show any error in VS Code when I type it inside my component; google.visualization is recognized.

```
import { GoogleChartComponent } from 'angular-google-charts';
...
let data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

However, when I run the server the graph doesn't show and I get the following error in Chrome debugger:

> ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined

Although the google.visualization library is recognized by VS code, it is not included in the project or component when I compile and run it.

How can I include it in a specific component or module?

I tried importing the classes I need from the directory, but  '@types/google.visualization/index' is not accepted. It says it's not a module.

It does work when i put those lines in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
```

But I am trying not to include the library in the header.